# I have an error in java(Netbeans).Any suggestions?

Tags: java, netbeans

This is the code.The code is enabled to extract the first letter from a person with 2 names but is unable to extract the first character with a person with 1 name since i am using split.

```
String name = jTextField1.getText().toUpperCase() + "";
String Surname = jTextField2.getText().toUpperCase().toString(); 
String Names[] = new String[1]; 
Names = name.split(" ");
int x = Names[1].length(); 
String initials = ""; 
if(x>0) {
    initials = (Surname)+" "+(Names[0].charAt(0)+"") +(Names[1].charAt(0)+""); 
    jTextArea1.append("Wakefileds property "+"\n"+initials); 
} else {
    initials = (Surname)+ " " + (Names[0].charAt(0) + ""); 
    jTextArea1.append("Wakefileds property "+"\n"+initials); 
}
```

Comment: `but is unable to do it` is not a valid problem statement. Please provide as many details as possible when describing in issue with code (expected output, actual output, example input/output, etc)

Comment: Note: in java, variable names should start with lower case letters.

Comment: They actually want the initials in capitals so i thought it would be easier to convert it to uppercase while im extracting it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my earlier comment at all.

Comment: `String Names[] = new String[1];` This is a useless initialization, since you replace it immediately on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
if (there are 2 words)
    //check both words
else
    //just check one word
```

Comment: No, it extracts the name and coverts it too capitals. The apostrophes are redundant but it does not effect the code.

Comment: @Merishan just do a check for when they're two words you get the first letter from both, please check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `if` statement to check whether the length of `Names` is greater than 1 and adjust your logic accordingly.